# some conflicts were found in the installtion area when upgrade Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio

Today, I updated android studio 1.3.2(build 141.2178183) to 1.4.0(build 141.2288178).
After I clicked the *Update and Restart* button, it downloaded the patch file.
But then it went wrong when installing the files.

> Some conflicts were found in the installation area.
>   Some of the conflicts below do not have a solution, so the patch cannot be applied.

[image]

Reinstallation will solve this, because this is the second time I encounter this scenario, but it is not a good solution.
I also googled a lot, but none can solve it.

Comment: I too was about to update my Android Studio but luckily I haven't done so yet.  I'll update and see if it breaks something on my machine

Comment: thx, waiting for you message @zulkarnain

Comment: I did update my Android Studio, but everything works on mine. Nothing breaks and no errors like the ones you've posted.

Comment: Okay.thx. Maybe I will try to reinstall it.@zulkarnain

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only solution is to re-download Android Studio, delete your old version of A.S., and then reinstall it.  Unfortunately clearing caches and restarting - alone - doesn't help.